# Is there a method like Array#index that returns multiple index if the argument is found multiple times?

Tags: ruby

`idols = ['Mahatma Gandhi', 'Martin Luther King Jr', 'George Costanza', 'Nancy Wake', 'George Costanza', 'John Howard Griffin', 'George Costanza']`

I want to issue `idols.indexes('George Costanza')` and get the result `[2, 4, 6]` -- every position at which my idol is George Costanza.

Is there an efficient or built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any in-built way of doing this I suppose, but you can do it using just a `map.with_index`.

```
def mul_indexes(arr,val)
    arr.map.with_index { |v, i| i if v == val }.compact
end
```

Now, you can use `mul_indexes(idols, 'George Costanza')`. Also, if you plan to make use of it too often, it would be better to make it `Array#mul_indexes`

Comment: If this is used commonly, making it `Array#mul_indexes` would make it easier to use.

Comment: `compact` makes this ugly. Consider using `each_with_index.with_object([])`. Also, you should wrap it in the class and `self.` is not needed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it doesn't make it ugly. When I ain't returning anything in the block, `nil` is assumed, which I'm just removing. And yeah. `self` isn't needed, because I had earlier made it a part of Array, but then removed it, without making the change to the code.

Comment: I amend my statement to say that I find it ugly.  After all, ugliness, like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder. You are creating a temporary array and then throwing away most of it.  Why do that when you can just get the bits you want directly?  For example: `class Array; def indexes(name); each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(s,i),a| a << i if s==name }; end; end; idols.indexes('George Costanza') #=>  [2, 4, 6]`.

Comment: When I said `self` wasn't needed I was assuming you were defining it on the class `Array`, where it's not needed because the receiver is `self` if not otherwise specified.  There's nothing wrong with adding an unnecessary `self.`; many Rubiests do. [I don't find *that* ugly; I just don't do it myself :-)]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with a singleton method:

```
def idols.mul_indexes
  each_with_index.inject([]) {|m,(e,i)| count(e) > 1 ? m + [i] : m}
end

idols.mul_indexes    # [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: This is a rather literal interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def indexes(arr, match)
  arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i] == match }
end

indexes(idols,'George Costanza')
  #=> [2,4,6]
```

I strongly advise against monkey-patching `Array` for this simple method.

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the Array class to implement that functionality

```
class Array
    def find_indexes(value)
        indexes = []
        self.each_with_index do |item,index|
            indexes << index if item == value
        end
        return indexes
    end
end
```

And then just do: `idols.find_indexes('George Costanza')`